# It works on jsfiddle but not on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery

i know there are already lots of question about it, but i didn't find my answer.

My code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WBkPH/2/) works but when i want to use it on my [website](http://commu-gamers.fr/), it doesn't work :s and i don't see what is the problem (not the encoding, the js is load in the body in the too case...)

Two cases :

1 : there is no $(document).ready

Nothing happend in any case.

2 : without the $(document).ready

When you click on "Et c'est reparti !" for example, the first condition is done, but if you click another time, nothing happen, whereas the second condition should be activate :(

The javascript :

```
function afficherToggle(c){
    if($(c).height()!='20'){
        $(c).stop().animate({ height: '20px',}, 600 );
    }
    else{
        $(c).animateAuto("height", 800); 
    }
}

jQuery.fn.animateAuto = function (prop, speed, callback) {
    var elem, height, width;
    return this.each(function (i, el) {
        el = jQuery(el), elem = el.clone().css({
            'height': 'auto'
        }).appendTo('body');
        height = elem.css('height'),
        elem.remove();

        if (prop === 'height') el.animate({
            "height": height
        }, speed, callback);
    });
}
```

Thank for your help !

Ps : Sorry for my English, if something is not clear, i'll try to explain with others words.

Comment: Are you including jQuery on your website?

Comment: make sure you have jquery connected to the page somehow...someway.

Comment: There is <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> so i think yes :)

Comment: He has a syntax error on his website, he's not ending the ready function correctly

Answer (score 4):

You didn't close `$(document).ready` add `});` at the end of your script.

Comment: Yes thank, I add it but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Look in firebug. ReferenceError: afficherToggle is not defined . May you need jQuery UI 1.9.2 library on your site

Comment: It was just a mistake because i was working on it. But even with it still doesn't work. The function animateAuto does nothing. http://commu-gamers.fr/index.php when you click on "Et c'est reparti !" for example, the first condition is done, but when you click an other time, animeAuto should be use and nothing happen.

Comment: If I put the  $(document).ready(function(){ ... });, nothing work, but without the first condition works :/